# Horizontal View remove default style

Tags: java, android, xml, horizontalscrollview

I have a horizontal scroll view, it is working fine. But I want to remove the default style it shows when you go right or left

This is my problem

[image]

How can I remove the orange color that is showing at the end or start of the Horizontal Scroll View?

Comment: I think its android OS feather. You can not remove it as per my knowledge.

Comment: @Hardy Can I use something other instead `HorizontalScrollView`, but to work like it?

Comment: Lets see what other user's answers regarding this. BTW good question.

Comment: Try to set `android:overScrollMode="never"` for `HorizontalScrollView`

Comment: @aim Can I ask you one more question. There is an "Add" button which adds a new tab. When there are a lot of tabs and I rotate my device all tabs are removed and just the last one stays there.

Comment: @Enve when you change rotation android recreate activity, as you know, so all you tabs will be recreated. You should keep this changes using [onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and then apply it manually with [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)). Or you can change activity configuration, so it will not be recreated. More detailed [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Answer (score 0):

set `android:fadingEdge="none"` at `HorizontalScrollView` in your layout